# Tomcat не запускает проект: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child

Tags: java, tomcat

Долгое время у меня всё работало, но сегодня абсолютно неожиданно решило сломаться. Причину я не понимаю, но при запуске томката получаю сообщение об ошибке, что мой проект нельзя запустить.

```
02-Mar-2023 18:20:05.946 SEVERE [main]
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying
web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT plus]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1184)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1932)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1094)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:476)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ROOT plus]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jawin/COMException
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3139)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:104)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5127)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jawin.COMException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
           ... 51 more
```

Либа на месте, класс на месте: вижу его перед сборкой в `Intellij Idea`, и абсолютно та же либа лежит в соседнем проекте, и он отлично запускается, без ошибок, всё работает.

И этот же проект в том же виде запускается на других машинах (копировал `ROOT` и вставлял туда).

Пробовал перезапускать компьютер, переустанавливать томкат, пересобирать проект. Не пойму, в чём может быть причина. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может версия java обновилась или берется не того места, установленного по умолчанию? `Intellij Idea` позволяет добавить jar файл как ресурс (правая кнопка мыши на `<library.jar>` -> Add as Library), при условии, если это не добавлено в сборщик проекта. Но это решит запуск проекта только локально, а на сервере нужно будет добавить в tomcat/lib библиотеку все равно.

Comment: Да нет, джава всё та же, джарники добавлены в проект. На сервере этот же самый проект отлично запускается - проблема только у меня локально)